# Regex: Get matching and "not matching" parts of string

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I am having a string like this:

```
%1n--%2n##%12n
```

I need all matches that match %1n, %2n, %12n and I also need all not matching parts. E.g: -- and ##

My regex pattern is `(%\d*n)(?!(%\d*n)*)`.

I get the matching parts (%1n, ...) and also empty matches from all non-matching parts. But the result for my example should be:

1. Match: %1n
2. Match: --
3. Match: %2n
4. Match: ##
5. Match: %12n

Can somebody tell me the correct regex pattern to get my expected result?

Comment: What is the programming language? Maybe all you need is `Regex.Split(text,@"(%\w+)")` (C#) or `s.split(/(%\w+)/)` (JS)

Comment: Maybe `%\d+n|.+?(?=%\d+n|$)`?

Comment: Or maybe: `%\d+n|(?:(?!%\d+n).)+`

Comment: Programming language is vb.net (or c#, but does not matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you may use `Regex.Split` with a regex wrapped with capturing parentheses to also return all substrings between matches:

```cs
var text = "%1n--%2n##%12n";
var result = Regex.Split(text, @"(%\w+)").Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/QwNi79). Output:

```cs
%1n
--
%2n
##
%12n
```

The `(%\w+)` regex matches and *captures* into Group 1 a `%` char and then any one or more word chars. If you only need to match ASCII letters/digits, use `(%[A-Za-z0-9]+)`.

See a [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/epqp7w), too:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(%\w+)"
Dim s As String = "%1n--%2n##%12n"
Dim matches As String() = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(s, pattern)
For Each m As String In matches
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(m) Then
        Console.WriteLine(m)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why did you think it should match `%` followed by word chars? Based on the OP's description and examples, I think they specifically want to match `%` followed by a number and then `n`. Otherwise, great answer as always :)

Comment: @41686d6564 It is a rule of a thumb in regex SO tag: select the simplest approach if there are multiple options. `\w` is the simplest construct when it comes to matching digits and letters (not precise, hence I suggested another pattern, yours is just another one). Also, `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)` can be replaced with `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` to preserve whitespace only items in the result.

Comment: Yes, `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` or `x.Any()` since `x` will never be null here (not `!x.Any()` as I wrote in my now-deleted comment; that was a typo).